# Why does pandas make a float64 out of an integer?

Tags: pandas

I set an integer as a cell value but Pandas does make a `float64` out of it. The question is why and how I can prevent that?

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame()
>>> df.loc['X', 'Y'] = 1
>>> df
     Y
X  1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't start with an empty DataFrame and then use df.loc[] to create columns.

E.g. start with a df with dtypes set

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3]}, dtype=np.int64)
```

or if you need to adjust the dtype of a column, then call the astype() method, e.g.

```
df["x"] = df["x"].astype("float")
```